# On expected waiting time and distribution of departure times in M/M/1 queue, condition on the number of departures

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation, operations-research, queueing-theory

Suppose we have an $M/M/1$ queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$. Let $S_i$ and $D_i$ denote the arrival time and departure time of the $i$-th customer, and fix $S_1$ as $0$.

Given that $n$ customers finish their services during time interval $[0, T]$ (i.e., $D_n \leq T$), what can we say about the (joint) distribution of $D_i,\ i = 2,\dots,n$? What is the expected total waiting time (i.e., $D_1+\cdots+D_n-S_2-\cdots-S_n$) of these $n$ customers?

From *Stochastic Processes* by Ross (Chapter 2), I know that $S_i\sim\operatorname{Uniform}([S_{i-1},T]), i = 2,\cdots,n$, if the given condition is '$n$ customers arrive during $[0, T]$'. However, I am not sure if we have a similar result in the above case.

I have been thinking about this problem for a long time. I will be very appreciative if anyone could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dollar signs are for math; you shouldn't use them for italic text – as you can see, the spacing comes out wrong. You can enclose text in asterisks to italicize it.

Comment: You didn't introduce $Y_n$. Is that supposed to be what you introduced as $D_i$?

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for the reminder. I just corrected the $Y_i$ and italic text mistakes.